# Trouble to get dynamic URL variables in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm displaying a chart with statistics on 10 days.

I'm now trying to set a button to change the offset to display 10 days before, then 10 days before, etc.

I did it using an url which contains the offset. Here is the code:

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^statistics/offset/(?P<off>\d+)$', views.viewStatistics, name='viewStatistics')
```

in my template, the button is:

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp.views.viewStatistics' off=off|add:"10" %}">
```

What I'd like to do is:

- if the current url page is `/statistics/offset/0`, the url of the button should be `/statistics/offset/10`
- if the current url page is `/statistics/offset/37`, the url of the button should be  `/statistics/offset/47`
- etc...

**Problem1:** the value in the generated URL is always 10 (which means `off` does not work and is probably binded to 0).

**Problem2** (nothing to do with problem1): I'd like to create a "next" button which do the opposite (if current url is X, the url of the button is X-10), but there is no `sub`template tag. I tried `add` with a negative value, does not work. I tried a custom django-mathfilter, does not work.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re. 1 — Do you pass current value of `off` to the template? Try rendering it next to the `<a>` using simply `{{ off }}`.

Re. 2 — `off|add:"-10"` – it [has to](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.5/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L660) work.

FYI, here's what happens if `foo` is not passed to the template:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> template = "{{ foo|add:'10' }}"
>>> Template(template).render(Context())
u'10'
>>> Template(template).render(Context({'foo': 10}))
u'20'
```

Comment: Yup, it would not throw an error in case `foo` is not passed to the template inside the context - instead it would treat `foo` as 0.

Comment: Yeahhh, it works!!! Thanks a lot. - Re 1: Indeed, I forgot to pass it (sorry..)  Re 2 - it raised an error because if the current offset was 0, the url was -10 and didn't match the regexp because of the minus character. I solved it with a simple `if`

Comment: @alecxe – see the link to the implementation. Django would not treat it as 0 in this case. Django would treat it as `''`, an exception on `int('')` would be raised and the result `'10'` will be returned thanks to string concatenation.